# Что значит password locked в CentOS?

Tags: centos, password

Вопрос скорее всего глупый, но я не могу найти внятного определения того, что такое locked password
Суть вопроса.
Достался мне в наследство сервер с postgresql 
И захотелось мне на всякий случай узнать, есть ли пароль на пользователе postgres.
Для этого я сделал следующее.

[root@SrvPgSQL ~]# passwd --status postgres

postgres LK 2016-07-27 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)

При этом если сделать

[root@SrvPgSQL ~]# su postgres

bash-4.1$

то заходит под этим пользователем без проблем. 
Отсюда вопрос, что значит locked password? Не могу найти понятного определения.
И значит ли это пароль на данном пользователе есть?

Comment: man `passwd -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выдержка из [`$ man 1 passwd`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=passwd&category=1)

> -l, --lock
>
> Заблокировать указанную учётную запись. Этот параметр блокирует учётную запись изменяя значение пароля на вариант, который не может быть шифрованным паролем.

если [точнее](https://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd), то:

> The locking is performed by rendering the encrypted password into an invalid string (by prefixing the encrypted string with an !)

перед хэшем добавляется символ `!`, превращающий хэш в «тыкву».

что делает невозможным аутентифицироваться под этой учётной записью **с помощью пароля**. конечно, остаётся возможность аутентифицироваться каким-либо иным способом, доступным в системе. например, как в приведённом примере, с помощью программы `su`.